# Calculating records per page

Tags: javascript, pagination, formula

Hi I am new to javascript. The formula that I am using for my application is calculating the wrong last page number. How it works is when a user enter the page range they want printed it should only print the page range from the start page to the end page. User  inputs are first page and last page. Thank you very much

```
    var rn = parseInt($('reportNumber').value) ;
    var s = parseInt($('startpage').value) ;
    var e = parseInt($('endpage').value) ;
    var l = parseInt($('linesPerPage').value) ;
    var i = (((e-s)+1)*l) ; // calculating the total number of records per page 
    createReport(rn,s,i)
```

In another function I am doing this for pagination:

```
   lastpage = Math.ceil(TotalNumberOfRows/recordsPerPage) ;
```

Comment: What JS library are you using? In jQuery, it should be `$('#reportNumber')` and so on -- you need `#` before the ID in selectors.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate records per page? Isn't that what `l` is?

Comment: I am using JQuery 1.9.1

Comment: Then you need to add `#` before all the IDs in the selectors.

Comment: That part of the code works fine

Comment: Are you sure you're not using Prototype.js?

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Records per page is in `$('linesPerPage')` so you don't need to calculate it. Or is there a difference between records and lines?

Answer (score 7):

You're dividing by the total number of rows in the page range, you should divide by the number of rows per page.

```
lastpage = Math.ceil(TotalNumberOfRows/l);
```

Comment: Sorry it is calculating records per page

Comment: No it isn't. It's multiplying records per page times the number of pages.